# Rx Exception Handling Fail

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm using RxJava with a retrofit to make API calls,

By using RxJava methods like **flatMap** and **map** I'm making API calls as well as performing DB operations in room database on the background thread.

My implementation is perfect and working fine if there is no error, but In the case when I got an error or any exception while performing DB Operation, Application getting crashed due to following Rx error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1

The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call.
```

I have used RxJava to perform my operation as below :

```
mDataManager.login(params)
                .flatMap { loginResponse: LoginResponse ->

                    // here making another API call based on previos API result
                    return@flatMap mDatamanager....
                }
                .flatMap { object: SomeDataModel ->

                    // here inserting data to DB
                    mDataManager.insertDataToDB(object).subscribe()

                    // here making another API call based on previos API 
                    return@flatMap mDataManager...
                }.map {

                    // here inserting data to DB
                    mDataManager.insertDataToDB(object).subscribe()

                    return@map true
                }
                .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
                .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
                .subscribe({ result ->
                    // updating view
                }, { throwable ->
                    throwable.printStackTrace()
                })
```

I'm getting an exception while inserting data to DB

Exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase:`

But the error not handled and Application getting crash.

The error says that `missing onError handler in the subscribe() method` but in my code, I already override throwable to handle exception/errors.

Can anyone find, what I'm missing or what mistake I have done in code.

---

**UPDATE**

Found the solution, Mistake was here :

`mDataManager.insertDataToDB(object).subscribe()`

In the Above statement, I'm subscribing but was not handling the error for that and because of that error was not handled by rxJava and in the result, the application gets crashed.

Final Code as below :

```
mDataManager.login(params)
            .flatMap { loginResponse: LoginResponse ->

                // here making another API call based on previos API result
                return@flatMap mDatamanager....
            }
            .flatMap { object: SomeDataModel ->

                // avoid this inner subscribe
                // mDataManager.insertDataToDB(object).subscribe()

                return@flatMap mDataManager.insertDataToDB(object)
            }
            .flatMap {
                // here making another API call based on previos API result
                return@flatMap mDatamanager....
            }
            .flatMap {

                // avoid this inner subscribe
                //mDataManager.insertDataToDB(object).subscribe()

                return@flatMap mDataManager.insertDataToDB(object)
            }
            .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
            .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
            .subscribe({ result ->
                // updating view
            }, { throwable ->
                throwable.printStackTrace()
            })
```

Above code is working Fine!

Comment: `mDataManager.insertDataToDB(object).subscribe()` is missing error handling

Comment: I tried by adding `doOnError` and `onErrorReturn` after data insertion, but not worked

Comment: what if in login api you got an error..
you need to handle onError before flatmap of login response

Comment: I guess that should be handled at the end on `throwable`

Comment: @Moinkhan not working as well I tried that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you are subscribing here

```
.map {
    // here inserting data to DB
    mDataManager.insertDataToDB(object).subscribe()
    return@map true
}
```

And this subscribe is not handling the error scenario.

I feel it's not a good practice to call subscribe() for the inner streams. In your scenario the flow is broken in-between.

The best way according to me is instead of using map and calling subscribe() here, use,

```
flatMap{
    object -> mDataManager.insertDataToDB(object)
}
```

This way, if any error, it will be caught in last outer subscribe().

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Thank for your answer!!, I have tried your solution but still not working!! getting same error.

Comment: Actually you are right, initially i only tried by replacing map with flapMap but then I  tried by avoiding subsribe inner flapMap for all flatMap and it's works!

Check my updated Question with solution.

Comment: Exactly as I mentioned, we shouldn't subscribe within a stream. It just breaks the complete chain.